# Are questions about IBR (UCR) reporting guidelines in Virginia on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

It would seem like questions related to IBR (UCR) reporting guidelines in Virginia may be on-topic on this site, since they're basically legal questions.  However they also would have a tendency to deal in validation errors, which are still somewhat of a legal matter in that particular context.  That might be slightly ambiguous as far as the site's topic goes.

For instance, the government of Virginia and Virginia State Police have a few PDFs that they've distributed that are supposed to explain the process, but what if you wanted to ask about the application of a rule you see in these documents?

Are these sorts of questions on-topic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Administrative rules that are enacted pursuant to law are at the outer limits of this site's scope.  The problem is that executive agencies are generally given broad discretion in implementing laws.  And so the answer to questions of the form, "Can they do that?" or, "Don't they have to do this?" is generally, "**They can do what they want as long as it complies with applicable laws.**"  And the fact that they *are* or *are not* doing something, and aren't stuck in court, is *prima facie* evidence that they are compliant with the law.

Furthermore, executive agencies are prone to promulgating unclear, vague, and even conflicting rules.  **The only way to clarify a question about their rules or processes is to ask them.  And even then, they can generally change their answer at any time and for almost any reason.**

The smaller the agency, and the less attention and resources given the law, the bigger this problem.  So, for example, we have seen good Q&A on administrative law pertaining to the IRS and INS.  But questions relating to HOAs tend to reduce to the information in the preceding paragraphs.